# Modulus optimization in a program

Tags: algorithm, optimization, modulo

I have seen that many people prefer to use in code:

```
 while(i<1000000){
       ret+=a[i];
       i++;
       if(ret >= MOD) 
          ret -= MOD;
   }
```

instead of making `ret%MOD` in the final step.

What is the difference between these two and how both these are equal?

How it is making an optimize our code?

Comment: mostly "in no way", nowadays. A modern optimizing compiler will probably detect in both cases that it's a modulo operation either way and emit the most efficient code on the particular architecture it's targeting (whether it be equivalent with `%` or `if` and a subtraction).

Comment: I doubt it, because the answer isn't always the same unless you change `if` to `while`, and that optimization has gotta be pretty low on the benefit/coding effort scale for all the optimizations the compiler author could choose to work on at any given moment.

Comment: but feel free to prove me wrong with asm output from your favorite compiler, I love to learn which optimizations compilers can do :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't tell without trying. There are two possible outcomes (considering my note further down below):

- The compiler optimizes the code in some way that both solutions use either a conditional jump or a modulo operation. This does not only depend on how "bright" the compiler is, but it also has to consider the target architecture's available instruction set (but to be honest, it would be odd not having a modulo operation).
- The compiler doesn't optimize the code (most probable for non-optimizing debug builds).

The basic difference that - as mentioned already -  the solution with the `if()` will use one conditional jump, which - again depending on your architecture - might slow you down a bit, since the compiler can't prefetch the next instruction without evaluating the jump condition first.

---

**One further note:**

Either using a modulo operation or your `if()` statement actually **isn't equal** (depending on the actual values), simply due to the fact that `ret % MOD` would result in the following equal code:

```
while (ret >= MOD)
    ret -= MOD;
```

Imagine `a[i]` being bigger than `MOD` and the new sum being bigger than two times `MOD`. In that case you'd end up with a `ret` bigger than `MOD`, something that won't happen when using modulo.

Answer (score 2):

Let an example :

13 MOD 10
what it actually do is, give you the reminder after dividing 13 by 10.

that is : `13 - (10 * (int)(13/10)) = 13 - ( 10 * 1 ) = 3`

so if `a[i] <= mod` then it will work good. but if `a[i] > mod` then see, what happens

```
let a[]= {15,15,15}

mod=7

in first step
ret = 0 + 15
ret = 15 - 7 = 8

2nd step
ret = 8 + 15 = 23
ret = 23 - 7 = 16

3rd step
ret = 16 + 15
ret = 31 - 7 = 24
```

So your final result is 24, but it should be 3.

you have to do :

```
while (ret >= MOD)
    ret -= MOD;
```

if you want to use subtraction instead of mod..

And obviously sub is better than mod in respect to time... because mod is really time consuming :(

Comment: *"And obviously sub is better than mod in respect to time... because mod is really time consuming :("* You can't be sure about this, since you don't know the actual values. Whatever is added to your sum first might be x times bigger than `MOD`, so you might end up with a for loop that's running for quite *some* time reducing the sum step by step (assuming it's not replaced/optimized out).

Comment: @Mario, for your concern, i know that :)
i meant if the mod is not very much bigger than maximum value...
because most of the problem uses mod=1e9+7... which is much bigger to do the sub :)
And obviously you are right :) if sum is x times bigger than MOD, then it won't be wise to do sub (y)

Answer (score 1):

It is best not to try to optimise code unless you have a performance problem. Then find out where it is actually having the problems

An to answer you question the two are the same - but you need to check with the particular hardware/compiler to check.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo requires integer division which is usually the slowest integer math operation on a CPU. Long ago before pipelines and branch prediction, this code was probably reliably faster than modulo. Nowadays branches can be very slow so its benefit is far from certain.  If the values in `a` are always much smaller than `MOD`, it's probably still a win because the branch will be skipped most iterations and the branch predictor will mostly guess right. If they are not smaller, it's uncertain. You would need to benchmark both.

If you can write the program such that `MOD` is always a power of 2, you could use bit masking which is much faster than either.

If I saw this pattern in code that wasn't 1) from 1978 or 2) accompanied by a comment explaining how the author benchmarked it and found it was faster than modulo on the current compiler, typical user CPU, and a realistic data input, I'd roll my eyes hard.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional test and subtraction is typically less expensive than a modulus operation, especially if the sum does not frequently exceed MOD. A modulus operation is effectively an integer division instruction, which typically has a latency which is an order of magnitude greater than that of compare/subtract. Having said that, unless the loop is a known performance bottleneck then you should just code for clarity and robustness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes booth compute the same thing but:

operation `%` needs integer division which is more time costly then `-` and `if`

- but on modern parallel machines (mean more pipelines by that not cores)
- the CPU do more tasks at once unless they depend on each other or brunching occurs
- that is why on modern machines is the `%` variant usually faster (`if` stalls the pipelines)

There are still platforms where the `-=,if` variant is faster

- like MCU's so when you know you have just single CPU/MCU pipeline
- or have very slow division then use this variant
- you should always measure the result ties during optimization process
- in your case you want to call just single mod per whole loop so it should be faster but check  the later text ...

Compilers

- modern compilers optimize code for your target platform and usually detect this and use the right choice
- so you should not be consumed by the low level optimization instead of by programing the task functionality
- but not all compilers are such for many platforms there are still used older compilers
- also in some rare cases the optimizations are preferred to be turned off
- because it could destroy specific desired timing, instruction patterns, or even functionality of the task ...
- in such cases there is no choice and this knowledge suddenly comes handy

**now the differences of your cases from algorithmic side:**

1. `while(i<1000000){ ret+=a[i]; i++; if(ret>=MOD) ret-=MOD; }`

- the sub result is still around modulo MOD
- that mean you do not need more bits then used for `max(a[i])+MOD*N` where `N` depends on `a[i]`
- if the `sum(a[i])` will go to bignums then this will have more speed due to no need to increase sub-result bit-width

2. `while(i<1000000){ ret+=a[i]; i++; } ret%=MOD;`

- this could overflow if variable `ret` can not hold the non modulo result

3. `while(i<1000000){ ret+=a[i]; i++; ret%=MOD;` }

- this is how it should be for bigger non modulo results

4. `if (ret>=MOD) ret-=MOD;` is not modulo operation

- it is just iteration of it.
- more safe is `while (ret>=MOD) ret-=MOD;`
- but if you know that the sub-result is not increasing too much (so it will not overflow in any few iterations) then `if` is OK
- but in that case you should add `while` or modulo after the loop to ensure correct result